# Can Test Subscriptions be Upgraded in Android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

So I have a set of subscriptions set up on my android app. The purchasing and cancelling work great. So I can both purchase the yearly, or the monthly and everything checks out.

However, whenever I try to test the upgrade from the monthly to the yearly, it errors out. It recognizes that I am upgrading, listing the past and the new subscription through Google's prompt. I then go through the billing prompts, accept all of them, then at the end I get an error message "Error, could not retrieve information from Server DF-CPA2-07x".

Has anyone had this problem before? I have tried restarting my app and phone, as well as clearing cache. I have also tried to reinstall and rebuild the app to no effect.

Comment: Perhaps you can share some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have the EXACT same situation with subscription testing that errors out on an "upgrade" attempt. Just one hour ago, I contacted Google Developer Support via chat. They were not able to help. However, they did say they would "investigate" and email me with a response. If I hear something I will post the answer.

Comment: Interesting. Okay, maybe it's a problem with the servers then. I guess I will have to test it live to see if it works there.

Comment: Just tested it live and it worked fine. Looks like it just doesn't work in testing.

Comment: @KurtAnderson, Thankyou! I will also test mine live to validate. I have still not heard back from Google Support, but will post again if I do.